# Problems with install hector quadrotor

Tags: ros, quadcopter, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install Quadrotor outdoor flight demo and just go through everything step by step as the tutorial.Unlucky, the mistake appears after catkin_make.I am a beginner of ROS and sorry for my English at the same time.could anyone kindly help me? If possible, I wish to know how to solve the problem.  Many thanks in advance!

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package joint_limits_interface.

Set joint_limits_interface_DIR to the directory containing a CMake
configuration file for joint_limits_interface.  The file will have one of
the following names:

```
joint_limits_interfaceConfig.cmake
joint_limits_interface-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'smartcar_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(smartcar_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'using_markers'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(using_markers)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186679/problems-with-install-hector-quadrotor/) by [flow wind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19734/flow-wind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flow wind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19734/flow-wind/) on 2014-07-15**:
In hydro system and 12.04 Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
cd ~/catkin_ws    # or whereever your workspace resides
rosdep install --from-path src --ignore-src     # This will install all required packages.
catkin_make
```

these code are so powerful nd iI have solve my problem.

---

Originally posted by [flow wind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19734/flow-wind/) with karma: 26 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorArias](https://answers.ros.org/users/34179/victorarias/) on 2018-03-16**:
thank you, this is the unique solution